# Expected number of vertex-pairs without any simple path in between

Tags: graph-theory, random-walk, random-graphs

Consider a random undirected graph $G(n, p)$, with $n$ vertices and each edge is added independently with probability $p$.

The goal is to find the expected number of vertex-pairs without any simple path (length $\leq k$)  in between.

Here is how I think about $k = n$: 
The expected number of isolated vertices is $n (1-p)^{n-1}$. Therefore the expected number of non-isolated vertices is $n(1-(1-p)^{n-1})$. Hence the expected number of vertex pairs WITH a simple path in between is 
$$
A= {n(1-(1-p)^{n-1}) \choose 2} 
$$
And the expected number of vertex pairs without a simple path in between is 
$$
{n \choose 2} - A
$$

For the case of $k< n$, maybe I can say this: 
The expected number of non-isolated vertices is the same. The expected number of vertices which have **(at least)** a path of length at most $k$ is: 
$$
A(k)= {n(1-(1-p)^{n-1}) \choose 2}  \sum_{l=1}^k {n(1-(1-p)^{n-1}) \choose l-1} (l-1)!p^l 
$$
And the expected number of vertex pairs without a simple path in between is 
$$
{n \choose 2} - A(k)
$$

Any comments on my solution?

Comment: The fact that two vertices $A$ and $B$ are not isolated does not mean that they are necessarily connected by a path... of *any* length.  $A$ and $B$ could be in unconnected subgraphs, for example.

Comment: Right. Any other suggestions for me?

Comment: Take two arbitrary vertices, $A$ and $B$.  Find the probability there is a path of length $1$ between them (as a function of $p$).  Next, find the probability that there exists a path of exactly length $2$ between them by summing over the $n-2$ such paths (defined by the mid-path vertex).  Next, find the probability that there exists a path of length $3$.  (Be sure to keep the order of points correct so as not to overcount.)  And so on.

Comment: For two fixed vertices, the probability that there is a path between  them of length at most $k$ is: $\sum_{l=1}^k { n-2  \choose l-1 } (l-1)!  p^{l} $. Am I correct?

Comment: @Daniel That is an upper bound for the probability. That is the expected number of paths of length at most $k$ between two specific vertices.